# Parsing of Multilevel array json throws undefined result

Tags: jquery, json

Below is the HTML and Json output.
Once if i click on button i can able to get the CurrentPage value whereas i couldn't able to get LongDescription value. Its throws me undefined. Please any one help on this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.button').click(function(){        
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://devcda.bryant.com/bryant/en/us/CommonSearchHandler.ashx?type=17&blogcategories=Air%20Quality",                 
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {                        
                     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#results').html('CurrentPage: ' + json.CurrentPage + '<br> LongDescription:'+ json.ResultPayload.LongDescription);


                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Json Data:

```
{
    "CurrentPage": 0,
    "Facets": null,
    "RecordCount": 1,
    "ResultPayload": [
        {
            "Name": null,
            "URI": "tcm:688-98798",
            "BlogCategories": [
                "Air Quality"
            ],
            "CreationDate": "January 01, 0001",
            "DisplayTitle": null,
            "LongDescription": "Test1",
            "PageURL": ""
        }
        {
            "Name":null,
            "URI":"tcm:688-98798",
            "BlogCategories":[
            "Air Quality"
            ],
            "CreationDate":"January 01, 0001",
            "DisplayTitle":null,
            "LongDescription":"Test2",
            "PageURL":""
        }
    ],
    "suggestions": null }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at: `json.ResultPayload.LongDescription` and now look at your json data. Your json data defines ResultPayload as an array (the [] indicates array), what you are attempting to address is as if it were an object. You need to first index the first element of the array and then target the property LongDescription. So you should use: `json.ResultPayload[0].LongDescription`

Comment: Hi if i have json format as above then how i should get my both LongDescription

Comment: You would have to loop at the `json.ResultPayload` level as it's an array. Or you can manually index each position.